# Error after deploying the Selenium Script on Google Cloud and Heroku

Tags: selenium, heroku

I have deployed my Selenium Script which runs across multiple web pages on a particular website and it works fine on my system but after deploying on Google Cloud and Heroku it is showing an Error after running. I found that the possible reason is memory limit was exceeded.

I have uploaded app.yaml, requirements.txt and main.py file on Google Cloud.
and Procfile, requirements.txt and main.py file on Heroku.

On both platforms it is showing error. Please help me out.

Comment: Does your selenium code open a real browser in your localhost? Attach the error

Comment: No. I have added disable option chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: It is showing something like this : <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>"

Comment: How are you managing the port? According to google, you are using django (python). Is the error related to the start on heroku or when you enter and perform some operation?

Comment: No, I am not using django

Comment: HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot ... is related to python. Share more details, logs, errors to your question

Comment: Hey there I have resolved the issue! The issue lied in Excess Memory Usage .Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem once when deploying my selenium script as well. 
For me it was indeed memory-related. 
There are a few ways I implemented to control memory use mainly by running a headless webdriver and by disabling extensions. 
For a chrome webdriver for example you can add the following options:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

I, on the other hand, had to monitor the navigation and interact with it via selenium-grid so I could not run it in headless mode and my solution was to simply add computational resources.

Comment: Hey!
I have added following chrome options:
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
Still getting the error.
Please help me out.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav! Can you share some details about the error: the trace back you get from this error and also when does it occur? does your Selenium testing start and then it stops with an error or does it not start at all?

Comment: It is showing something like this : <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>"

Comment: Hey there I have resolved the issue! The issue lied in Excess Memory Usage .Thanks for help

Comment: That's great! :)